# What is fastest way to do geospatial search in snowflake?

Tags: sql, optimization, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, geospatial

I am new to geospatial field and data, recently needed a geospatial search that I need as a feature in my model. The idea is fora given point A, how find nearest 10 points within 20 miles. Based on documentations and search I ve found many geo functions and created this query that searches and returns nearest point:

```
INSERT INTO candidate_table (ref_id, longitude, latitude, geom)
SELECT
 ref_id,
 longitude, 
 latitude, 
 ST_POINT(longitude, latitude)
FROM
 input 
LEFT JOIN
 list_of_points USING (ref_id) 
;
```

```
INSERT INTO subject_table (ref_id, longitude, latitude, geom) 
SELECT 
 ref_id, 
 longitude, 
 latitude, 
 ST_POINT(longitude, latitude) 
FROM 
input 
LEFT JOIN 
   list_of_points_b USING (ref_id) 
;
```

```
--it is working
 
SELECT 
  s.ref_id AS subject_ref_id, 
  c.ref_id AS candidate_ref_id, 
  ST_DISTANCE(s.geom, c.geom) AS distance_mi 
FROM subject_table s 
JOIN candidate_table c 
ON ST_DWITHIN(s.geom, c.geom, 20 * 1609.34) 
WHERE s.geom IS NOT NULL AND c.geom IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY s.ref_id, ST_DISTANCE(s.geom, c.geom) 
;
```

However this method creates a search that is very slow, way more slower than I thought. I know a geospatial index makes things faster and i know snowflake supports h3 index functions. Is it the way to makes is faster or what would you recommend ?

Comment: in the last query, instead of using 20*1609.34, use 32186.8.  Remove the Order By clause. Dump the results into a temp table. Perform the sorting on the temp table. This removed 1 extra ST_Distance call per record. Simplifying the queries in this way may help find better index use. At the very least you can now isolate what part of the query needs optimization.

Comment: Much like date ranges, non equi-joins are slow. Where spacial queries are two dimensions verse the one of time. But if you use some from of bucketing to can generate 10 to 100  time the regions of interests but get very fast matching using exact equi-join matches.

Answer (score 1):

firstly to get your miles distance you will want to correct out of meters.

```
ST_DISTANCE(s.geom, c.geom)/1609.34 AS distance_mi
```

alrighty, lets build so random data in the valid lat,lon range, and see how many rows we need to take long than a seconds to run the "slow query":

```
-- 100K
create or replace table c_table_100K as
select
    seq8() as id,
    random()/(9223372036854775807/180) as lon,
    random()/(9223372036854775807/90) as lat,
    ST_POINT(lon, lat) as geom
from table(generator(ROWCOUNT=>100000));

create or replace table s_table_100K as
select
    seq8() as id,
    random()/(9223372036854775807/180) as lon,
    random()/(9223372036854775807/90) as lat,
    ST_POINT(lon, lat) as geom
from table(generator(ROWCOUNT=>100000));
```

so this SQL using those tables, takes 3.6s:

```
SELECT 
  s.id AS s_id, 
  c.id AS c_id, 
  ST_DISTANCE(s.geom, c.geom)/1609.34 AS distance_mi 
FROM s_table_100K as s 
JOIN c_table_100K as c 
    ON ST_DWITHIN(s.geom, c.geom, 20 * 1609.34) 
WHERE s.geom IS NOT NULL AND c.geom IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY s.id, ST_DISTANCE(s.geom, c.geom);
```

dropping the ORDER BY, the query takes 3.8s so it's free.. or not the cost
pre computing the math (32186.8), which the optimizer also does, 3.6s, again free.

swapping to using the calculated result, aka:

```
SELECT 
  s.id AS s_id, 
  c.id AS c_id, 
  ST_DISTANCE(s.geom, c.geom)/1609.34 AS distance_mi 
FROM s_table_100K as s 
JOIN c_table_100K as c 
    ON distance_mi <= 20 
WHERE s.geom IS NOT NULL AND c.geom IS NOT NULL
```

I ran it, and as of 5 minutes, the right leg had only process 3.8K of 100K rows, so the CartesianJoin slow code, appears it would take ~2h19m. lets not go there.

[image]

looking at that 3.6 JOIN time in the profile we see it doing a GEO_JOIN, so I would suspect we might struggle to perform a better join, given the distance filter, is most likely being use to bucket the data under the hood, into chunks and then doing the bucket matching. I would suspect my normal, lets hand roll this, will just get lost in the edge case of the polls, so ST_DWITHIN should be considered the best option, and the next best thing todo, as those null checks show is pre-filter any other details that can be known, as "not the points we are looking for" prior to the join.